# calendar keep going on getting the previous month

Tags: javascript

I'm building my small calendar with plain javascript (so please no jquery) and I have trouble to make the prev month display
So far this is my code for get previous month:

```
document.getElementById("prev-month").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    console.log('first', prevMonth);
    prevMonth = monthNamesArray[currentMonth - 1]; //Array with all the month labels like ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'];
    month.innerHTML = '<td>'+ prevMonth +'</td>'; //Here i replace the html cell where the month is display
    console.log('second', prevMonth); 
});
```

The console.log of the two debugger is:
First click: first undefined second September(the previous month)
Second click: first September second September

Why the during the second click the second console log didn't became second August ? 
Why the prevMonth go back just one month?

Any help, in particular an explanation, is really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't update `currentMonth`, still points to `october`.

Comment: ah-ha! Thanks! How I cannot see it!

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you need prevMonth, as to keep it updating correctly you would ideally write it as:

```
currentMonth = monthNamesArray[(currentMonth==0)? 11 : currentMonth-1];
```

The ternary operator ensures that at January you don't go `monthNamesArray[-1]`, but it instead wraps back to `monthNamesArray[11]`.

EDIT:
Both directions, the direction variable can be any size integer value, so you could go direction = -2 and it will go backwards 2 months.
currentMonthIndex is the index for the current month 0 to 11.

```
var remainder = (currentMonthIndex + direction) % 12;
currentMonth = monthNamesArray[Math.floor(remainder >= 0 ? remainder : remainder + 12)];
```

Comment: Cool! that was my next steps! :)